# Step-by-step Kashering: Hag'alah

Tags: chametz-leaven, kashering-kosherization, how-to

What is the step by step process of Kashering for the method of Hag'alah?

Assume I've never done it before, and I am taking a recently used, non-Kosher metal pot and a number of cutlery and cooking tools for Passover. (Maybe I'm in a hotel.) It all needs to be made Kosher, Parve, and Pesachdik.

See also:

- ['Iruy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27311/step-by-step-kashering-iruy)
- [Libbun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27314/step-by-step-kashering-libbun)

Comment: I think we need to make a "how to" tag.

Comment: @Fred I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Of course CYLOR. I've had to ask HaRav Mansour Shalit"a a question about Halacha once about Haga'ala.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but you really have to state according to who's opinion you want the answer.  There are those that pretty much say you can not do what you are asking, down to some very lenient opinions.

Comment: @mekubal, who says you cannot Kasher a metal pot and cutlery????

Comment: @ SethJ the entire Eida HaChareidit says that cookware cannot be kashered through hagala, walk around meah shearim and see their authorized boiling locations with large signs that specifically say that.

Comment: @Fred Done. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

1) Make sure everything to be kashered is clean and has not been used for 24 hours.

2) Boil water in a Kosher pot.

3) Place the utensils to be kashered in the pot, make sure they are surrounded by water and make sure the water continues to boil.

4) Remove the utensils and rinse with cold water.

As always, CYLOR.

Source: Star-K 2013 Passover Directory

Comment: In all fairness I can name you at least four modern Gedolim who say the process as you just described it, will not work for Pesach, one of which is the current chief Ashkenazi Rabbi of Israel.

Comment: @mekubal Can you explain what is missing? (ben yomo maybe or other things...)

Comment: @mekubal, ditto DoubleAA's comment. Who says you can't Kasher metal Keilim? Since when? I asked for step-by-step. I agree that this answer is incomplete, because step one should be wait 24 hours. Other than that, what's the issue?

Comment: Also, Andrew, I believe running cold water over them is the final step.

Comment: @SethJ I thought that might be the case, but some quick (really quick) researching I did made me think otherwise. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mekubal Why not??

Comment: @DoubleAA Let's see.  According to Rav Metzger the kelim have to be Aino Ben Yomo, completely clean, and immersed in a boiling vat that contains a volume at least 60x the volume of the vessels that one is immersing, and that bleach or some other taam lifgam has to be added to the boiling water.  Not something most people can do on their own.
To be continued...

Comment: Now according to most opinions of which I am aware in this regard(Rav O. Yosef, Rav Eliashiv, Rav Metzger) if one exceeds the 60:1 ratio by even the slightest amount, say 60:1.001, then the water, and the vat, and everything inside becomes chametz.  Which is why in E"Y at the various city boiling stations, they often will not allow cooking utensils to be immersed, and will inspect your kelim.

Comment: @mekubal that may be the case, but now I added a source for _my_ answer (which I happen to think is the more generally practiced one).

Comment: @andrewmh20 What is or isn't the more generally practiced opinion(which is highly debatable under the best circumstances) is irrelevant to the point.  The point being that this is a question that is nearly impossible to give a definitive answer and universal answer to.

Comment: @mekubal There doesn't have to be a universal answer. Any answer that cites according to which opinion it is answering is valid. You are welcome to post another answer with more views. And in Judaism, there are _always_ more views :)

Comment: @mekubal, That opinion of Rav Metzger is very interesting. Is it written anywhere that I can read? Does it have explanations? (I'm no expert, but wouldn't bleach and aino ben yoma be redundant? Maybe that's the whole point?)

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to andrewmh20's answer, some rules to keep in mind:

- In general, one should not even try to kasher anything they are afraid might break in the attempt. This could lead to the kashering being inadequate.
- Cutlery where the handle is a separate piece (i.e., knives) have a serious problem, in that unless one disassembles it, one cannot be certain that no chametz be'ein got inside. In fact, on most knives, it's even too difficult to remove the *visible* chametz on the seam. If you cannot be *absolutely certain* that there is no mamashos of chametz inside, you cannot kasher it. (This applies to knives more than say, pot handles, since food touches the seam of a knife handle in common use, but pot handles not as much.)

Feel free to add more rules if you think of any, or post them in your own answer, and as always, CYLOR

---

<sup>Sources: Shulchan Aruch HaRav, 451:20

Please do add more if you know them.</sup>