# 'Kashering' a milchig knife to make it parve (using hagalah)

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization

I have 3 questions:

1. Can a milchig (or fleishig for that matter) knife be kashered to become parve by means of hagalah?
2. If it can be done, does a parve pot need to be used to contain the boiling water or can it be a milchig/fleishig pot?
3. Do the knife and pot have to be left unused for 24 hours before using it?

Comment: It certainly can be done in ordinary circumstances, though many have a custom to refrain from doing so.

Comment: Dupe of part 1? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7496/759 dupe of part 2/3 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27312/759?

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems like those 2 answers pretty much answer my question as well. Does that mean this question should be taken down?